# Response API in different languages JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

im having an issue trying to make a response from my API in the selected language from the header with:

> Accept-Language: es-MX or Accept-Language: en-US

```
function getLanguage (req, res, next) {
  let lang = req.acceptsLanguages('en-US', 'es-ES');
  console.log(lang)
  next()
}

app.use(getLanguage)
```

Well, i got the correct language but i dont know how to send the json with only the data in the selected language. The response send me both colors.

Example of my JSON:

```
"teams": [
  {
    "id": 0,
     "color": {
        "en": "Blue",
        "es": "Azul"
      }
    },
    {
     "id": 1,
     "color": {
        "en": "Red",
        "es": "Rojo"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this solucion help you.

```js
let lang = "en"

let teams= [
  {
    "id": 0,
     "color": {
        "en": "Blue",
        "es": "Azul"
      }
    },
    {
     "id": 1,
     "color": {
        "en": "Red",
        "es": "Rojo"
    }
  }
]

teams = teams.map(item => {
  item.color = item.color[lang]
  return item
})

console.log(teams)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using something like localize module

```
var Localize = require('localize');

var myLocalize = new Localize({"color": {
        "en": "Blue",
        "es": "Azul",
        "de" : "Blau"
      }
     });

myLocalize.setLocale("es")
console.log(myLocalize.translate("color")); // prints Azul 
myLocalize.setLocale("de")
console.log(myLocalize.translate("color")); // prints Blau
```

For further details read
https://github.com/AGROSICA/node-localize

Answer (score 0):

Create function for selected language like :

```js
const teamsOnString = `[
  {
    "id": 0,
     "color": {
        "en": "Blue",
        "es": "Azul"
      }
    },
    {
     "id": 1,
     "color": {
        "en": "Red",
        "es": "Rojo"
    }
  }
]`

const teamsOnJson = JSON.parse(teamsOnString)

function selectLanguage(lang) {
  let filteredLang = teamsOnJson.map((items) => {
    items.color = items.color[lang]
    return items
  })
  return filteredLang
}

let enLanguage = selectLanguage('en')
console.log(enLanguage)
```